# Create a Month function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to run a query that runs monthly but it will check daily if the timestamp from the records is from the previous month.  If yes then it will run the query and append to the previous monthly data.

So, I want to create a simple function to return TRUE if the RecordTimestamp is from the previous month. Something like this:

```html
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION isMonth(recordTimestamp TIMESTAMP) AS (  xxxxxxx );
```

What would be right syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return TRUE if the RecordTimestamp is from the previous month

Use below

```
create temp function isPrevMonth(ts timestamp) as (
  date_trunc(date(ts), month) = date_trunc(current_date() - interval 1 month, month)
);
```

Comment: Great! Glad it works for you! Please also consider voting up the answer :o)